# Сообщение удалено, редактирование невозможно?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, правки, удаление-вопросов

Если попробуете отредактировать вопрос по [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/931343/edit) незарегистрированным или low-rep пользователем, то увидите сообщение:

> Сообщение удалено, редактирование невозможно.

Но пользователи с необходимой репутацией вполне могут [редактировать удалённые вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/931343/revisions).

Comment: Я думаю, тут привязка к 10к. Можешь смотреть - можешь и редактировать.

Comment: @älёxölüt но сообщение об ошибке не совсем корректное. Должно быть что-то типо "вам пока не доступно это и ссылка на страницу привилегий".

Comment: менять формулировку надо на MSE предлагать.

Comment: @älёxölüt задам чуть позже MSE.

Comment: Ага. Задайте им там!